# Append sub-elements to its parent element only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to convert a bunch of menu dropdowns into multiple  elements. I have been able to do this when theres only one dropdown on the page but once I add the others, my script seems to run through each menu multiple times. I am new to Javascript/Jquery but I was wondering if there was a way to make it only input to its parent element?

Here is my current script that works for a single dropdown:

```
$('.mylinks li').each(function() {
  var inputClass = $('.mylinks .link').html().toLowerCase();
  $('body').prepend('<select class="'+inputClass+'" onchange="window.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value"></select>');
  $('a').each(function() {

    var linkName = $(this).html();
    var linkVal = $(this).attr('href');
    $('select').append('<option value="'+linkVal+'">'+linkName+'</option>');
  
  });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="mylinks">
  <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Drop 1</a>
        <a href="http://geartrade.com">Link 1</a>
        <a href="http://geartrade.com">Link 2</a>
        <a href="http://geartrade.com">Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Drop 2</a>
        <a href="http://geartrade.com">Link 1</a>
        <a href="http://geartrade.com">Link 2</a>
        <a href="http://geartrade.com">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul> 
 </div>
```

I have an example of this error here as well: http://jsfiddle.net/UdTcF/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.mylinks li').each(function () {
        var inputClass = $('.mylinks a').html().toLowerCase();
        var select = $('<select class="' + inputClass + '" onchange="window.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value"></select>');
        $('body').prepend(select);
        $(this).find('a').each(function () {
            var linkName = $(this).html();
            var linkVal = $(this).attr('href');
            select.append('<option value="' + linkVal + '">' + linkName + '</option>');
        });
    });

});
```

Use a variable `select` to save the `<select>` you want to add, and late can add `<option>` to this variable using `select.append()`.

And use `$(this).find('a')` instead of `$('a')` to find `<a>` in certain `<li>` but not all `<a>`.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UdTcF/1/).

Comment: In addition to the code, please provide an explanation as to why it is correct so as to foster growth on Stack Overflow

Comment: ah man that's brilliant. Thank you! What is the reason behind using $(this).find('a') rather than just something like $('.mylinks li a')?

Comment: @user1524879 `$('.mylinks li a')` still find all `<a>` in all `<li>`. While `$(this)` is a certain `<li>`, and `$(this).find('a')` find the `<a>` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
$('a').each,
```

you're selecting all a elements. I think that you want to select just only those in the current li. SO, just replace add:

```
$('a',this).each,
```

it will select only a elements which are children of this, eg the li element.